# How to create mapping for additional class inside some class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two classes: `Order` and `User`

`Order` has `User` class inside of it:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

I have NHibernate mapping for both of them:

For User:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="Purchasing" namespace="Purchasing.Other">
  <class name="User" table="tUser">
    <id name="RID">
      <column name="RID" sql-type="bigint"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Created"/>
    <property name="Modified"/>
    <property name="UserName"/>
    <property name="Email"/>
    <property name="ExternalUserId"/>   
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I tried to add `User` class to `Order` mapping, BUT looks like something is wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Purchasing" namespace="Purchasing.Other">
  <class name="Order" table="tOrder">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="OrderId" sql-type="bigint"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="DataOwnerId" />
    <property name="UserId" />
    <property name="OrderNo"/>
    <property name="FirstTaken"/>
    <property name="DateRequired" />
    <property name="ExternalOrderId" />
    <many-to-one name="User" class="User" property-ref="ExternalUserId">
      <column name="UserId" not-null="false"/>
    </many-to-one>     
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have a situation, when, writing Order in tOrder database, I also need to write its User to tUser database.
But looks like it didn't work. *(Order mapping without User map works fine)*.

How in this situation mapping should look correctly, and what am I missing?

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your mapping with `property-ref` seems to be OK. But the statement: *I also need to write its User to tUser* is a bit unclear. The mapping above, once you will assign user to Order, will write the `UserId` int column `ExternalUserId' in the table `tOrder'. That's it. Nothing else. This is wrong? You want new `User` - just assigned to order - to be inserted as well? Is this the issue?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert not only Order, but User also, and so far I don't have any idea how to do it

Comment: Then you should use cascading, e.g. cascade="save-update"... that should do the job

Comment: Not sure how it supposed to look

Answer (score 0):

If we want to persist `User` with its `Order`, we can use cascading setting:

[5.1.10. many-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

> An ordinary association to another persistent class is declared using a many-to-one element. The relational model is a many-to-one association. (It's really just an object reference.)

```
<many-to-one
        name="PropertyName"                                (1)
        ...
        cascade="all|none|save-update|delete"              (4)
        ...
/>
```

> **(4)**   **`cascade (optional):`** Specifies which operations should be cascaded from the parent object to the associated object.

So the mapping could be like this:

```
<many-to-one name="User" class="User" 
        property-ref="ExternalUserId" 
        cascade="save-update"
        column="UserId" not-null="false" 
/>
```

Now, we only have to be sure, that we try to find a user (it could be existing)

```
var user = session.Get<User>(userId);
if(user == null)
{
    user = new User { ... };
}
```

And then we can assing that user to the Order

```
var order = new Order { ... };
order.User = user;
```

and calling session to persist Order - user will be as well:

```
session.SaveOrUpdae(order);
```

NOTE: if you can reference user by its native ID ... it would be better. Mapping then would look like:

```
<many-to-one name="User" class="User"             
        cascade="save-update"
        column="RID" not-null="false" 
/>
```

Mapping with `property-ref` should be used exceptionally